# Creating unique names for uploaded images

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    $img4='';
    $target4='';
    echo uniqid();
    echo date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");

    if(isset($_FILES['img4']))
    {
        $file_name = uniqid().date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").$_FILES['img4']['name'];
        $img4 = uniqid().date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").$_FILES['img4']['name'];
        $target4 = "images/allimagesad/".$file_name;
    }
```

```html
echo"<img src='images/allimagesad/".$row['img1']."' style='max-height:82px; ; max-width:145px ;' title='' alt='' />";
```

generate unique name is working... but  cant display image . please help me

Comment: If you check that directory, do the image files exist?

Comment: Hi @kavinda and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I suggest that you add a bit more context to your question. What exactly are your trying to do? Are you getting any error messages? Have you researched other sites to try to find the answer to your question? Here is a link to some tips for asking great questions on Stack Overflow, hope this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: thank you comment my massage... , that image uploading code successfully work.. work i cant display image..

Answer (score 0):

```
$uniqId = uniqid();
$file_name = $uniqId.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").$_FILES['img4']['name'];
$img4 = $uniqId.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").$_FILES['img4']['name'];
```

You need to save result of uniqid() to variable, because every calls of uniqid() gives you new value.

Comment: thanx for commenting my post... i want to know ... how to display that image....echo"<img src='images/allimagesad/".$row['img1']."' style='max-height:82px; ; max-width:145px ;' title='' alt='' />"; this is my code...... upload code is working but cant display value

Comment: Did you check you upload directory? Are the files exists in upload directory?

Comment: if(isset($_FILES['img1'])){
   
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img1']['tmp_name'],$target))

   {
    $msg = "successfully";
   }
   else
   {
    $msg = "somthing trubble";
   }
  }

Comment: this is image my image upload code... i think problem is here